# Session PHP não funciona em diretórios diferentes

Tags: php, session

Tenho um sistema onde o diretório do gerenciador encontra-se como subdomínio:

> gerenciador.site.com.br

Ao acessar o gerenciador, é gerado uma session conforme abaixo:

```
$_SESSION["Logado"] = true;
```

A sessão funciona corretamente dentro do subdomínio, entretanto dentro do gerenciador tenho um link que direciona para a pasta raiz sem target:

```
<a href="http://site.com.br/album/">Álbum de fotos</a>
```

Como estou usando o jQuery-File-Upload, coloquei na pasta raiz, pois ao fazer o upload das imagens, ele armazena as fotos dentro do diretório files e com isso acaba mostrando o diretório do gerenciador. Dentro do index.php do diretório acima, chamo a sessão novamente:

```
session_start();
if($_SESSION["Logado"] == true){
....
```

O problema é que parece que ao mudar de diretório, a sessão não funciona. Existe alguma solução alternativa? Estive pensando em direcionar para um arquivo chamado redirecionar.php na pasta do álbum e recriar novamente a sessão e vice-versa.

Answer (score 1):

Como é em um subdomínio diferente ele não ta encontrado os cookies, existe diversas soluções, pode tentar botar antes do session_start:

```
ini_set('session.cookie_domain', '.site.com.br');
```

Se isso não funcionar, tenta:

```
session_name('site.com.br');
```